# Azure AD B2C login not working from Visual Studio

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am working to get Azure AD B2C set up and working.  And it is working, when published.

However, when I run the project from Visual Studio, it runs fine until I click the Login Button. At that point, the configuration forwards to the expected azure login URL, but it then immediately forwards to the published app.

The published app then gives this error message:

```
Error. An error occurred while processing your request.

Details
Unable to unprotect the message. State.
```

In doing searches on this error message, it basically says that the wrong app is trying to process the request.  And this is true, it is not localhost that is processing it, it is the published app.  The published app should have nothing to do with logging in from localhost, so this makes no sense to me.

Before the app was published, it DID log in fine from localhost.  After publishing the app, I could still log in successfully both from localhost, and the published app.  It started failing after I hooked up the API Connector to an API to process the "Before Registration" webhook.  It was at this point that localhost stopped being able to log in, even though the web hook and local host have no connection whatsoever.

I have tried started over with an entirely new App, a new Azure AD B2C set up etc.  And all works fine until the Webhook is wired up.  This makes no sense whatsoever to me.  I have spent hours checking all settings I can find, but still I can't make it work in Visual Studio.  There is no additional data in the browser console window, or on the network tab.

Have tried rebooting and eating a bag of chips as well.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I was able to get this working.

In case anyone else ends up with this issue, here is how I fixed:

1. The trouble comes from the Redirect URI's here:
   [image]

This is part of the "App Registration" in the "Overview" section.

2. Click on the link and review the URL's.  There should be two, and only two.

[image]

A. For the Dev environment. This should look like this:  `https://localhost:1234/signin-oidc`  If there are several, check you visual studio launchsettings.json file to see what the port should be.  Remove any other ones so there is only one localhost uri.

B. For the Production Environment.  This should look like this:  `https://MyApp.Azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc`

C. Ensure you hit the save button at the bottom of the page, or you will be fooled into thinking you saved your changes and didn't actually change them.

D. Wait an hour before testing again.  The data is stored in Azure AD, and it takes time for it to replicate around the Azure servers.  It's not an instant update like I thought it would be.

E. If you have any unnecessary AppRegistrations, remove them. For example, if you were testing.

F. The automatic configuration through the VS Wizard does NOT correctly set up the above URLs. Ok, sometimes it does, but not always.  Not sure why, but the above is the fix.

Hope this helps.  The Official [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#register-an-application)